# Unit of Work - Doctrine - Notice: Undefined index: 00000000571faff30000000066f110c7

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entitymanager, unit-of-work

I manage a data import treatment in async with RabbitMQ.
If i lauch the consumation message, it's work the first time, but if a send a the same message again, i've got an error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: 00000000571faff30000000066f110c7
```

I thought it was because i use `$em->clear / $em->getUnifOfWork()->clear()` in my script but no; i try to reset the manager to have a new manager on each message treatment but it doesn't work. (`$this->managerRegistry->resetManager();`)

I have commented `$this->entityManager->clear();` to see if the problem happen but the script is now very slow to accomplished the method `importUserHierarchy` and the problem is still there.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Service\Import\User\Insert;

use App\Entity\Document;
use App\Message\Import\User\Insert\ImportUserReportFailMessage;
use App\Message\Import\User\Insert\ImportUserReportSuccessMessage;
use App\Model\Import\SpreadsheetInsertUser;
use App\Service\Import\ImportEngine;
use App\Utils\Memory;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

class SubmitImportUser
{
    public const BATCH_FLUSH_DATA = 100;

    private $entityManager;
    private $managerRegistry;
    private $userRowMapper;
    private $userHierarchyMapper;
    private $logger;
    private $importEngine;
    private $bus;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
        UserRowMapper $userRowMapper,
        UserHierarchyMapper $userHierarchyMapper,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ImportEngine $importEngine,
        MessageBusInterface $bus = null,
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->userRowMapper = $userRowMapper;
        $this->userHierarchyMapper = $userHierarchyMapper;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->importEngine = $importEngine;
        $this->bus = $bus;
    }

    public function import(Document $document)
    {
        $nbUsersUpdated = 0;
        $nbPopulationUpdated = 0;

        $rows = $this->importEngine->convertFileToArray($document);
        $nbUsersUpdated = $this->importUserDatas($rows);
        $nbPopulationUpdated = $this->importUserHierarchy($rows);
    }

    public function importUserDatas(array $rows): int
    {
        foreach ($rows as $line => $row) {
            $row = array_slice($row, 0, SpreadsheetInsertUser::SIZE_COLS);
            $user = $this->userRowMapper->addUpdateUser($rows, $row);
            $this->logger->info(sprintf('IMPORT - User with reference %s added successfully to persistence',
                $row[SpreadsheetInsertUser::COL_USER_REFERENCE]));
            $this->entityManager->persist($user);

            if (0 !== $line && 0 === $line % self::BATCH_FLUSH_DATA) {
                $this->entityManager->flush();
            }
        }

        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return count($rows);
    }

    public function importUserHierarchy(array $rows): int
    {
        $this->userHierarchyMapper->truncatePopulation();

        $populationDistances = $this->userHierarchyMapper->computeHierarchy($rows);

        $nbPopulationLine = 0;

        foreach ($populationDistances as $refManager => $refUsers) {
            foreach ($refUsers as $refUser => $distance) {
                ++$nbPopulationLine;

                $population = $this->userHierarchyMapper->addUpdateHierarchy($refManager, $refUser, $distance);
                if ($population) {
                    $this->entityManager->persist($population);
                }

                if (0 !== $nbPopulationLine && 0 === $nbPopulationLine % self::BATCH_FLUSH_DATA) {
                    $this->entityManager->flush();
                    $this->entityManager->clear();
                }
            }
        }

        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return $nbPopulationLine;
    }
}
```

So i don't known what to do :(
I use Symfony 4.4
If someone got an idea in unit of work management to explain to me what happen ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

So in my function `importUserDatas` and my sub-function `addUpdateUser` to avoid doing query to the database for each new sub-object created, i put my object in a php array. So when i use `clear()` fonction the reference doest'nt work because this entity manager object clean objects with their references.

I decide to do not put new object on php array and now it's work perfectly

Comment: Although you've solved your problem, Doctrine also has the ability to [detach entities](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) from management which may or may not help you. There is also a [second-level cache](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/second-level-cache.html) that, although experimental, should be fairly safe for simple data in a read-only content.

Comment: I have a similar error, I wonder if you can shed some light:
       

     $alarmData = new Alarm();
     $alarmData->setAlarmCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
     $alarmData->setAlarmMessage($alarm->getAlarmMessage());
     $alarmData->setDevice($message->getDevice());
     $this->em->persist($alarmData);
     $this->em->flush();

There was an issue about persisting the relationship device. It is a ManyToOne, so I added:

     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Device::class, inversedBy="alarms", cascade={"persist"})